# Ruby HTTP sending API key Basic_auth

Tags: ruby, header, authorization

I have been following a tutorial on [GitHub Pages](http://danknox.github.io/2013/01/27/using-rubys-native-nethttp-library/) and 
I am trying to pass an Apikey to a webservice as basic auth 'apiKey' => 'huda7da97hre3rhr1yrh0130409u1u' for example but I cannot work out how to implement it into the method, or even if that is the proper place for it.

I have a class called connection with my request method in it. I need to post 'apiKey' as header and not in the body. I have read the ruby docs but I cannot work out how to apply it to this specific class.

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "ostruct"
require "json"


class Connection
    ENDPOINT = "http://localhost"
    APP_LOCATION = "/task_manager/v1/"

VERB_MAP = {
    :get    => Net::HTTP::Get,
    :post   => Net::HTTP::Post,
    :put    => Net::HTTP::Put,
    :delete => Net::HTTP::Delete
}

def initialize(endpoint = ENDPOINT)
    uri = URI.parse(endpoint)
    @http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
end

def get(path, params)
    request_json :get, path, params
end

def post(path, params)
    request_json :post, APP_LOCATION + path, params
end

def put(path, params)
    request_json :put, path, params
end

def delete(path, params)
    request_json :delete, path, params
end

private
def request_json(method, path, params)
    response = request(method, path, params)
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)

    OpenStruct.new(:code => response.code, :body => body)
rescue JSON::ParserError
    response
end

def request(method, path, params = {})
    case method     
    when :get
        full_path = encode_path_params(path, params)
        request = VERB_MAP[method.to_sym].new(full_path)
    else            
        request = VERB_MAP[method.to_sym].new(path)
        request.set_form_data(params)
    end
    @http.request(request)
end

def encode_path_params(path, params)
    encoded = URI.encode_www_form(params)
    [path, encoded].join("?")
end

end
```

If I post to the server using Advanced Rest Client and put the apikey in the

```
http://localhost/task_manager/v1/tasks?=
```

header

```
Authorization: 9c62acdda8fe12507a435345bb9b2338
```

and in the body

```
email=free%40mail.com&password=free&task=test
```

then I get

```
    {
error: false
message: "Task created successfully"
task_id: 5
}
```

So how can I post it using this class?.

```
        connection = Connection.new
        result = connection.post("task", {'task' => 'task'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Authentication example:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'
```

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Basic+Authentication

Or if you want to add a raw Authorization header in your request method you can do

```
 request.add_field 'Authorization', 'huda7da97hre3rhr1yrh0130409u1u'
```

But basic authentication normally means that there is a user name and a password. With your API key - I am not sure you actually need basic authentication. I do not know what you API actually requires but if you have not tried it yet you can try sending the api key as an additional parameter

```
result = connection.post("register", {'email' => email, 'name' => name, 'password' => password, 'apiKey' => 'huda7da97hre3rhr1yrh0130409u1u' })
```

Comment: Sorry mate I have the docs and I cannot seem to intergrate it with my class. I have updated my post with the complete code

Comment: You can add headers using add_field method request.add_field 'Authorization', 'huda7da97hre3rhr1yrh0130409u1u'

Comment: thank you so much, I wasn't aware you can just add Auth fields like that. Much appreciated.